# Apache Ignite on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, arm, raspberry-pi3, ignite

I'm currently working on a project involving a distributed Apache Ignite DB on a cluster of Raspberry Pi.
I want to have 2 separate data regions including one with persistence enabled. Here is my custom config :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration" id="ignite.cfg">


<property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">

        <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="default_region"/>

                <!-- Set max cache size to 50 MBytes-->
                <property name="maxSize" value="#{50 * 1024 * 1024}"/> 
                    
                <!-- Specifiying an eviction policy that evicts the latest used data when the data hits 90% of the max storage capacity-->
                <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_LRU"/>
                <property name="evictionThreshold" value="0.9"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        
        <property name="dataRegionConfigurations">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="persistence_region"/>

                    <!-- Set max cache size to 100 MBytes-->
                    <property name="maxSize" value="#{100 * 1024 * 1024}"/> 
                    
                    <!-- Enable persistent data storage -->
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>

<property name="authenticationEnabled" value="true"/>

<property name="discoverySpi">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="ipFinder">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                <property name="multicastGroup" value="228.10.10.157"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>

</bean>
```

I built my own Docker image with my custom conf based on the official Dockerfile except that I changed the base image with: `FROM arm32v7/openjdk:8-jre-alpine`

The troubles begin when I try to start my image... I have some warnings such as :

```
Nodes started on local machine require more than 80% of physical RAM what can lead to significant slowdown due to swapping (please decrease JVM heap size, data region size or checkpoint buffer size) [required=1300MB, available=924MB]
```

And then several errors like :

```
[SEVERE][tcp-disco-msg-worker-[crd]-#2-#46][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=disco-notifier-worker, threadName=disco-notifier-worker-#45, blockedFor=11s]
```

After that, it's impossible for me to activate the cluster (through REST, or the control.sh script) and to query it.

If someone has a config file working on Rpi I'm really interested!

EDIT :

I have tried with @alamar 's suggestion (-Xmx384 and checkpoint page buffer size of 20M) but I still have theses errors when activating :

```
[SEVERE][rest-#68][GridTcpRestProtocol] Failed to process client request [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=90 lim=90 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=1, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1607710531775, hashCode=9092883, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1-#39]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:11211, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:59558, createTime=1607710503680, closeTime=1607710511719, bytesSent=2, bytesRcvd=96, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1607710533267, lastSndTime=1607710503680, lastRcvTime=1607710511719, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=o.a.i.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@1eb05], routerClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true, markedForClose=true]], msg=GridClientAuthenticationRequest [cred=SecurityCredentials [login=ignite], super=GridClientAbstractMessage [reqId=1, id=b2d7025f-e4a0-4ab7-8c3e-92e2c1c4aea9, destId=null, super=o.a.i.i.processors.rest.client.message.GridClientAuthenticationRequest@18dd064]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message (connection was closed): GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=90 lim=90 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=1, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1607710531775, hashCode=9092883, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1-#39]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:11211, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:59558, createTime=1607710503680, closeTime=1607710511719, bytesSent=2, bytesRcvd=96, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1607710533267, lastSndTime=1607710503680, lastRcvTime=1607710511719, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@1eb05], routerClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true, markedForClose=true]]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7589)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.resolve(GridFutureAdapter.java:260)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:172)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:141)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestNioListener$1$1.apply(GridTcpRestNioListener.java:296)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestNioListener$1$1.apply(GridTcpRestNioListener.java:293)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:399)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.listen(GridFutureAdapter.java:354)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestNioListener$1.apply(GridTcpRestNioListener.java:293)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestNioListener$1.apply(GridTcpRestNioListener.java:261)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:399)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.unblock(GridFutureAdapter.java:347)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.unblockAll(GridFutureAdapter.java:335)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:511)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:490)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:467)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor$2$1.apply(GridRestProcessor.java:187)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor$2$1.apply(GridRestProcessor.java:184)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:399)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.listen(GridFutureAdapter.java:354)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor$2.body(GridRestProcessor.java:184)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to send message (connection was closed): GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=90 lim=90 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=1, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1607710531775, hashCode=9092883, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-1-#39]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:11211, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:59558, createTime=1607710503680, closeTime=1607710511719, bytesSent=2, bytesRcvd=96, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1607710533267, lastSndTime=1607710503680, lastRcvTime=1607710511719, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@1eb05], routerClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true, markedForClose=true]]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer.send0(GridNioServer.java:642)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer.send(GridNioServer.java:583)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onSessionWrite(GridNioServer.java:3693)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedSessionWrite(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:121)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onSessionWrite(GridNioCodecFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedSessionWrite(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:121)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onSessionWrite(GridNioFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onSessionWrite(GridNioFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioSessionImpl.send(GridNioSessionImpl.java:117)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestNioListener$1.apply(GridTcpRestNioListener.java:290)
        ... 16 more
```

Result of "control.sh --set-state ACTIVE" :

```
Control utility [ver. 2.10.0-SNAPSHOT#20201013-sha1:a2fa7ec3]
2020 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
User: root
Time: 2020-12-11T18:19:04.421
This cluster requires authentication.
Connection to cluster failed. Latest topology update failed.
Command [SET-STATE] finished with code: 2
Control utility has completed execution at: 2020-12-11T18:19:56.559
Execution time: 52138 ms
```

Thank you!

Comment: I created this for use on a Raspberry Pi 4: https://github.com/sdarlington/ignite/packages/317604 But as @alamar says, the main problem is you're requesting more memory than your Docker/Pi has available.

Comment: Thank's @StephenDarlington! I tried with your image it seems to be working perfectly! What did you do to make it work?

Comment: "This cluster requires authentication" did you authenticate? Please try `--verbose`, also attach complete log to user list message. See https://ignite.apache.org/community/resources.html

Answer (score 2):

People did start it occasionally on Rpi.

In your case, please try decreasing JVM's Xmx (-Xmx384 will be OK) and also specify checkpoint page buffer size for persistent region explicitly (20M should be OK in your case).

If you still see "threads blocked" exceptions, please share complete log. You may use Apache Ignite userlist for that. Also, please describe what happens when you try to activate.

Comment: I edited my question with the things you asked! What is Apache Ignite user list ?

Comment: @Edwind it's a mailing list that's more suitable for long term discussions. Check the docs for the details https://ignite.apache.org/community/resources.html and here is an example of UI http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things here.

First, I don't think you needed to update the Docker file. A Pi3 has 64-bit cores, so the default should work. I created [this one](https://github.com/sdarlington/ignite/packages/317604) and it works fine on a Pi4.

Second, between your JVM and your data region, you're allocating more memory than your Pi has:

> Nodes started on local machine require more than 80% of physical RAM what can lead to significant slowdown due to swapping (please decrease JVM heap size, data region size or checkpoint buffer size) [required=1300MB, available=924MB]

You only appear to have 150Mb for off-heap, so I wonder how big you Java heap is? 8Gb should be plenty.

If your Pi is swapping to disk, that might be causing the blocked system threads.

Finally, since you enabled authentication, you need to supply a username and password when you try to activate the cluster. The default appears to be ignite/ignite.

Comment: I tried a little bit more with your image and I still have some weird issues when I'm using my config (2 data regions with 1 persistent, authentication, etc.). Sometimes when I try to activate cluster with control.sh it tells me that it needs authentication although I specified user and password (ignite for both) and when I try to reach the node with thin client I have "Request is not completed due to the connection lost" in the thin client but nothing in Apache Ignite...